# How can I setup the pro license key for liquibase in spring boot gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, java-8, liquibase

I could not find where I need to add the liquibase pro key in the spring boot Gradle project. Below is my project structure. please assist me to put the license key.

## My project structure

resources

-----> db

----------->changelog

```
  ----------->db.changelog-master.yaml
  ----------->db.changelog-1.0.yaml
  ----------->liquibase.properties
```

application.properties

in Master yaml file

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      file: db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.yaml
```

application.properties

```
spring.liquibase.enabled=true
logging.level.liquibase=debug
```

liquibase.properties

```
liquibaseProLicenseKey: ABww..........
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to [this link](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/creating-config-properties.html) and [this link](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/springboot/using-springboot-with-maven.html) for some help with your question.

The first link above says,

> **Adding your Liquibase Pro license key**
>
> In the example below, to add your Liquibase Pro license key, just add the
> liquibaseProLicenseKey: attribute to your liquibase.properties file
> and add your license key. Then save your file.
>
> ```
> changeLogFile: ../path/to/file/dbchangelog.xml
> driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
> url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.22:1521/orcl
> username: PRO
> password: password
> referenceDriver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
> referenceUrl: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.22:1521/orcl
> referencePassword: password
> liquibaseProLicenseKey: aeioufakekey32aeioufakekey785463214
> classpath: ../path/to/file/ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.0.jar
> ```

For help with liquibase setup in Gradle Spring Boot, you may want to refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52517215/setup-liquibase-in-a-gradle-spring-boot-hibernate-project)